# How to refer to an inner class method with its simple name in JavaDoc?

Tags: java, reference, javadoc

I want to make method reference from documentation, but I know how to do this in this way `{@link Main.MainInner.mainInnerMethod()}`, but in the documentation the user see `Main.MainInner.mainInnerMethod()` - it's too long. What if I want the user(of the code) to see only `mainInnerMethod()`?

I know I can do this `{@link Main.MainInner.mainInnerMethod() mainInnerMethod()}`, but if I decide to rename `mainInnerMethod` to `someMethod`, then the the user will see `mainInnerMethod()` in the documentation instead of `someMethod()`, so is there a way to get the simple name of method and put it in the documentation, so if the method is renamed the documentation will be updated too?

I'm just interested, I don't really need this in practical situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the javadoc is on another method of `MainInner`, then you just specify the method name: `{@link #mainInnerMethod()}`

If the javadoc is elsewhere, you must give at least the class name. If the class is `import`'ed, you don't have to qualify it: `{@link MainInner#mainInnerMethod()}`